# What app should i get to help open Starmade/Minecraft

Tags: minecraft

I have downloaded Starmade (minecraft in space basically) and I want to open it but I don't know what to use or download to play it. The default is squeeze but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Java runtime to run the game.
To install it, run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` in a terminal. You can then run the game by double-clicking the .jar file (if it opens in Archive Manager instead, right-click it and select Open With > OpenJDK) or from a terminal by running `java -jar ./StarMade-Starter.jar` from the folder where the file is stored.

Comment: When I type java./StarMade-Starter.jar it says no such file directory

Comment: You have to go to the directory where you saved Starmade on download first. Also there must be a space between “`java`” and the rest of the command.

Comment: What if it says: could not find or load main class?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to type `java -jar ./StarMade-Starter.jar`

Comment: Just so you know im doing this on a Samsung arm chromebook with Ubuntu.

Comment: You either don't have the file, have renamed it or you didn't `cd` to the folder where it is located before running the command.

Comment: cd to the folder?

Comment: I just typed sudo java -jar ./StarMade-Starter.jar and the launcher opened up yay

Comment: Okay the download for the update says 100% and I still can't press start game or start dedicated browser. The buttons are both greyed out

Comment: Now when the launcher dissapears after i click play and set up the game noting happens